# Standard Windows 11 Icons incl. Color in UWP apps

Tags: uwp, icons, windows-11

I would like to build an UWP app that looks *native* to Windows 11, especially when it comes to the toolbar icons. I like the new Windows Explorer icons and I am looking for a resource where I can find them.

[image: Windows 11 icons with multiple colors]

I've found information about the **[Segoe Fluent Icons](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/style/segoe-fluent-icons-font)** font and how to use them, but they all appear to be in one color. I would like to have the two color or possible more colors combination, as Windows 11 does. Is Segoe Fluent Icons the correct approach? Are there standard icon resources for the Windows 11 standard icons in multicolor?

Answer (score 0):

> Standard Windows 11 Icons incl. Color in UWP apps

I have to say, above icon is specific custom for Window 11, we can't use them directly in your own app. but we could make it with Icon layering that is a technique used to overlap two different glyphs. For more info please refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/signature-experiences/iconography). And you could also make double colors icon image to replace.

```
<Grid>
    <FontIcon
       Margin="0,0,22,0"
        FontFamily="{StaticResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}"
        Glyph="&#xE74b;" />
    <FontIcon  
        FontFamily="{StaticResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}"
        Foreground="SlateBlue"
        Glyph="&#xE74a;" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: "above icon is specific custom for Window 11".

At least the common icons like the cut/copy/paste/delete/print should look the same within all Windows 11 apps.  Shame that they made them specific for Win 11. 

BTW, I cannot find glyphs that when overlayed with two colors will produce the icons that Win 11 uses.

Comment: Well, if you do want this two colors icons please feel free post your requirement within WinUI [github](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml).